# How to mock/stub a Java object in C# code?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, nunit, ikvm, nmock

My C# code is using a class written in Java (IKVM). That Java class provides 2 methods that I am calling in my C# code:

1. GetInstance() - It simply returns the instance of that Java class.
2. GetSet() - returns a java.util.Set that I iterate over to do some processing.

We use NUnit and NMock and I am relatively new to mocking/stubbing, so I am quite confused on how to write unit test cases for this piece of C# code which will return a Java object etc.

Any help/pointers would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used IKVM, but I strongly suspect it will be wrapping the java objects with .Net objects so mocking/testing is going to be largely the same as for any other code.  You are likely to get a better response if you can include a minimal example of the code you want to to test, along with your attempt at creating a test for it and any errors that you encounter.

Comment: @forsvarir actually there's no wrapping whatsoever, the Java bytecode is recompiled to MSIL by ikvmc (**if** you use ikvmc), so you get regular .Net classes. They feel very Java-ish :) but you can mock them just like any other .Net code indeed.